# gzip не сжимает часть страниц сайта

Tags: drupal, gzip

Сайт на Друпал 7 проверяю работу gzip [сервисом](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/) часть сжиматься часть нет. В частности страницы с адресом https://itmc.travel/en**/tours/**... не сжимаются.
В чем может быть проблема? Пример:[сжиматся](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/?url=aHR0cHM6Ly9pdG1jLnRyYXZlbC9lbi9jYXRlZ29yeS9tb3VudGFpbmVlcmluZw==) / [не сжимается](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/?url=aHR0cHM6Ly9pdG1jLnRyYXZlbC9lbi90b3Vycy9sZW5pbi1wZWFrLTcxMzRt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Включить сжатие страниц ../tours/.. с помощью mod_gzip не получилось. Добавил в .htaccess дерективы для  mod_deflane и все заработало.

- AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
- AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
- AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
- AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
- AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
- AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
- AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
- AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
- AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript